# Разбить строку на массив по этому символу `→`

Tags: python, строки

Моя строка содержит эти символы `→`. Насколько я понял это `Unicode Character “→” (U+2192)`. Как я могу 'string.split('')` по этому символу ?

Comment: Использовать этот символ как аргумент, не?

Comment: `string.split('→')`?

Answer (score 1):

(Я использую гугл переводчик)

Я считаю, что вам просто нужно скопировать и вставить '→' в ваш код. Например:

```
x = "первая часть → вторая часть"
y = x.split('→')
print(у)
```